# Build RPM on Windows with Cygwin but install on Linux

Tags: rpm, cygwin, rpmbuild

I am trying to figure out an issue that I have with installing an RPM file on openSUSE which I build on Windows (using Cygwin/rpmbuild).

When I try to install the RPM on Linux I get an error saying

```
package <package>.rpm is intended for a different operating system
```

The RPM is build by calling

```
rpmbuild --nodeps --target=i386 --buildroot="$BUILDDIR" -bb $ROOTPATH/tmp.spec
```

I can force the installation by installing it with --ignoreos, but if there is a way to avoid it.
I've been rummaging through the rpm macros file in Cygwin, but I've not been able to find the correct setting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literally 5 seconds after I've posted the question, I found the answer.
The rpmbuild command is incorrect; if I execute

```
rpmbuild --nodeps --target=i386-linux --buildroot="$BUILDDIR" -bb $ROOTPATH/tmp.spec
```

everything works correctly and I can install the resulting RPM on Linux.